# Enviar un Arreglo asociativo multidimensional mediante el uso de formularios

Tags: php, html, post

De un formulario como este:

```html
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
  Foo: <input type="text" name="foo"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sabemos que para acceder clásicamente a la información recibida por el método `POST` de `php` es:

```
$_POST['foo']
```

Que internamente sería algo como esto:

```
/*arreglo obtenido por el método POST*/ [
    'foo' => 'bar'
]
```

Ahora bien ¿Qué tendría que modificar en las etiquetas `html` para recibir algo como esto?

```
[
    'name' => 'example of name',
    'activities' => [
        '0' => [
            'activity' => 'eat'
            'time' => '15:45:12'
            'reason' => 'some explanations'
        ]

        '1' => [
            'activity' => 'sleep'
            'time' => '21:07:12'
            'reason' => 'some explanations'
        ]
        //Se repite N número de veces
    ]
    'rpe' => 'example of rpe',
    'occupation' =>
]
```

Teniendo en cuenta que el formulario (al ser dinámico) lo genero con `JavaScript`.

---

**NOTA**: Quiero saber que es lo que tengo que modificar en las etiquetas `html` y como acceder a la información, obviando la generación mi formulario; cualquier ejemplo que tenga la esencia de lo que quiero lograr, está bien.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no te hace falta JavaScript o procesar/convertir los campos a JSON antes de enviar el formulario. En PHP puedes usar notación de corchetes que te autogenerará un array asociativo cuando se procese el formulario en el lado del servidor.

Igual que si tienes un campo con corchetes se genera automáticamente un array  en PHP cuando se envía el formulario, puedes definir los índices de ese array y el servidor hace el trabajo por ti. Sólo tienes que asegurarte de que los índices de los corchetes son correctos en tu HTML y después PHP se encargará del resto.

Por ejemplo, con el siguiente formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="wow.php">

    <input type="text" name="name" />

    <input type="text" name="activities[0][activity]" />
    <input type="text" name="activities[0][time]" />
    <input type="text" name="activities[0][reason]" />

    <input type="text" name="activities[1][activity]" />
    <input type="text" name="activities[1][time]" />
    <input type="text" name="activities[1][reason]" />

    <input type="text" name="rpe">
    <input type="text" name="occupation">

    <button>Submit</button>

<form>
```

cuando hago un `print_r($_POST)` lo que obtengo es el array asociativo:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Alvaro
    [activities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [activity] => Jugar
                    [time] => 1
                    [reason] => Game time!
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [activity] => Estudiar
                    [time] => 2
                    [reason] => Estudiar es bueno
                )

        )

    [rpe] => 12
    [occupation] => Programador
)
```

que es lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 2):

Y si en lugar de enviar los datos del formulario de esa forma recoges los valores y los envías por medio de un JSON? Si es posible, seria una buena forma. Tanto en JS como PHP tienes funciones para trabajar con ello.

En PHP tienes [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)/[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), en JS tienes [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify).

[Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2433843/6118054) a respuesta SO en ingles que tratan sobre el tema, usando array en los formularios y recogiendo valores en PHP.

Comment: Sí, es una solución más elegante, pero requiero hacerlo únicamente mediante `php`, es por eso que en la pregunta menciono **¿qué es lo que tengo que modificar en las etiquetas html?**. Aún así, tomaré en cuenta lo que mencionas para un futuro.

Comment: Tambien puedes usar arrays para un elemento que envies por POST, como en el caso de los checkbox(yo la verdad que solo lo he usado en ese caso).

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, bien puedes hacer uso de los DATASET para guardar mas información de tu input, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como poder agregar datos a los DATASET del input. El ejemplo esta desarrollado con JQUERY, espero te sirva.

```js
$('#go').click(function() { //Aquí pues un simple click del div que hace funcion de boton, puedes colocar lo que tu ocupes.
  
  //Lo siguiente solo es pleno ejemplo, deberas adecuarlo a tus necesidades.
  
  /*Yo voy a consumir un JSON mediante una página libre*/
        var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'; //URL de la página 
        $.ajax({
          url: root + '/posts/1', //url con metodos y variables.
          method: 'GET' //uso de GET como Método de Consumo
        }).then(function(data) { //Cuando termine de consultar.
          var a = $("#datos"); //Buscamos el input con id datos
          var b = JSON.stringify(data); // los datos que vienen del consumo los convertimos
          
          //aqui viene el punto clave de la solución
          a.attr("data-a",b); //Vamos a insertar los datos que vienen del consumo en los DATASET del input, entonces creamos el data-a y le agregamos los datos de la variable b.
          a.attr("data-b",b); //como pleno ejemplo hago lo mismo pero ahora con el data-b, tu puedes agregar tantos DATASET como gustes
     console.log("Datos del DATASET a: "+ a.attr('data-a'), "datos del DATASET b: "+a.attr('data-b'));
          
          //OJO: Tu puedes nombrara como gustes a los DATASET, pero siempre con la norma de: data-tunombre, data-otronombre, data-masnombre....
        }
               );
});
```

```css
#go:hover{
cursor:pointer;
  background:yellow;
  color:red;
}
#go{
width:80px;
background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="datos">
  <div id="go">click aqui</div>
</form>
```